# What is the generic purpose of do/end blocks in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

I am struggling with Ruby do/end blocks.
For instance, I have the following example:

```
::ApplicationController.class_eval do
  def close_sdb_connection
    puts "Closing sdb connection."       
  end
end
```

What this piece of code does? Why we need blocks? What would be the equivalent code without the do/end blocks?

Comment: What your questions is about: do/end blocks or `class_eval` function?

Comment: Maybe both. I would like first to understand the generic purpose of do/end blocks and their equivalent in other languages. Are they anonymous blocks?

Comment: [This article](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do` and `end` are reserved words. They have no generic higher purpose (at least until Matz goes nuts like Larry Wall and says they do). In your sample code, the external `do ... end` means the code block – same as `{ ... }`. The internal `end` serves as the right delimiter of the `def ... end` method definition.

In the context of `class_eval`, the code sample in the OP does exactly the same thing as:

```
class ::ApplicationController
  def close_sdb_connection
    puts "Closing sdb connection."
  end
end
```

However, block statements, such as `Foo.class_eval do ... end` significantly differ from non-block statements, such as `class Foo; ... end`, as the blocks are closures over local variables.

It is interesting to note, that [not each `do ... end` indicates a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396475/ruby-for-loop-a-trap).

Comment: And in the context of class_eval what does this block does? thanks!

Comment: google for [Ruby `yield` `block_given?`] for the inside story. do-end takes a block of code and passes a handle to it into a method. That method can then store the handle to evaluate it later, or evaluate it right now. The method can change conditions before and after calling that block. The method can also change how that block looks up its variables. That's what that `class_eval` is doing.

Comment: thanks. If I have the following code: `tag 'children:first' do |tag| ... end` what is the role of 'children:first'? the first param of `tag`?

Comment: @pinker: 'children:first' is a string, that has no special meaning to Ruby as such. It is the duty of the `#tag` method programmer to describe the method arguments and their meanings in the method's documentation, if ze hasn't done so, complain.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a `do` ... `end` or `{` ... `}` block is used to put code inside that is not to be evaluated in the same way as the rest of the code. In particular, a block is evaluated under a certain binding (i.e., a certain assignment of local variables and the `self` keyword) at a certain timing for a certain number of times, all of which is controlled by the method that the block is attached to.

In this particular case, the block is evaluated with a binding different from the outside. Particularly, the code inside would be evaluated as if it were inside the class body of the receiver `::ApplicationController`.