# check_box_tag includes n+1 query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following line in a list of stories an article belongs to—on an edit article page, allowing me to assign the article to stories—works but produces an n+1 query (I think).

The bit that is causing the problem is `@article.stories.include?(s)`, which checks to see if an article already belongs to a story:

```
<%= check_box_tag "article[story_ids][]", s.id, @article.stories.include?(s) %>
```

Log says Rails is doing 50+ queries (all stories) because of that one bit; article_id = 266 in the example:

```
Story Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "articles_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "articles_stories"."story_id" WHERE "articles_stories"."article_id" = $1 AND "stories"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["article_id", 266], ["id", 6]]
Story Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "articles_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "articles_stories"."story_id" WHERE "articles_stories"."article_id" = $1 AND "stories"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["article_id", 266], ["id", 51]]
Story Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "articles_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "articles_stories"."story_id" WHERE "articles_stories"."article_id" = $1 AND "stories"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["article_id", 266], ["id", 41]]
Etc., etc.
```

The actual number of stories article_id = 266 belongs to is…2:

```
 select * from articles_stories where article_id = 266;

 article_id | story_id 
 ------------+----------
    266 |       35
    266 |        5

 (2 rows)
```

How do I fix it?

**UPDATE: DB, whole chunk & controller**

Article.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :stories
```

Story.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
```

And the whole chunk of code the check_box_tag is in—prints a list of stories by category you can assign to an article—is:

```
<% @stories.group_by(&:category).sort_by{|c, stories| c.category}.each do |c, stories| %>
  <div class="admin-stories-in-categories">
    <strong><%= c.category unless c.nil? %></strong>
      <ul>
        <% for s in stories %>
          <li>
            <%= check_box_tag "article[story_ids][]", s.id, @article.stories.include?(s) %>
            <%= s.story %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In articles_controller.rb:

```
@stories = Story.all.includes(:category).order(:story)
```

**ANSWER:**

AbM's answer below makes the N+1 queries go away and instead returns a single query:

```
Returns `(0.8ms)  SELECT "stories"."id" FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "articles_stories" ON "stories"."id" = "articles_stories"."story_id" WHERE "articles_stories"."article_id" = $1  [["article_id", 266]]`
```

Comment: There is a lot of question and tips to fix n+1 query, have you tried something?

Comment: I have. They didn't work, hence the question. You edited out "Happy New Year"?

Comment: Why didn't work? Could you be more clearly, what is not work and what is you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks because the `include?` method on a active record relation does an `EXIST` operation in sql if the relation is not loaded as shown [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/include%3F)

Try storing the article stories in a variable:

```
<% article_stories_ids = @article.stories.pluck(:id) %>
<% @stories.group_by(&:category).sort_by{|c, stories| c.category}.each do |c, stories| %>
  <div class="admin-stories-in-categories">
    <strong><%= c.category unless c.nil? %></strong>
      <ul>
        <% stories.each do |s| %>
          <li>
            <%= check_box_tag "article[story_ids][]", s.id, article_stories_ids.include?(s.id) %>
            <%= s.story %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: please dont use `for` loops in ruby

Comment: I just used their example for the existing loop. The modification is just for storing the ids in a variable

Comment: Ok, thanks @AbM, that works. Will post what it returns.

Comment: Why not @Зелёный? What's the alternative?

Comment: Updated the answer to use `.each` instead of `for` loop

Comment: Is there some performance difference between `.each do` and `for x in xs`?

Comment: @MatthewBennett https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396475/ruby-for-loop-a-trap

Answer (score 1):

We need your database schema and the query you're using from your controller (if any) — but you'll likely just have to do something like `Article.includes(:stories).find(params[:id])`

I'd recommend plugging in something like Bullet into your development stack.

https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Comment: I added the relations and controller bits.