# Comparing object equivalence in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a Ruby tutorial here:
http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/105-equality_of_objects

It's saying when I overload the `==` operator that I should also overload the `eql?` method and hash methods because they are "faster".

However, if I am overloading all three with essentially the same method, how is one faster than the other?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257096/why-is-faster-than-eql

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa: Turns out it's not really related, but I was happy to be able to answer that tough question :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In most cases, `==` and `eql?` have the same result. In some cases, `eql?` is more strict than `==`:

```
42.0 == 42 # => true
42.0.eql?(42) # => false
```

Because of this, if you define `==` you probably want to define `eql?` also (or vice versa).

A choice was made that the `Hash` class would use `eql?` to differentiate between different keys, not `==`. It could have been `==`, mind you, but `eql?` was cleaner.

To avoid doing expensive calls to `eql?` all the time, a hash value is calculated with the requirement that two object that are `eql?` must have the same hash value. That hash value is stored, which makes future lookups very easy: if the hash code does not match, then the values are not `eql?`...

For that reason, you must define `hash` in a sensible way if you define `eql?`.

Note that calculating the hash value is almost always more expensive than doing a comparison with `==` or `eql?`. Once the hash is calculated, though, checking that the hashes matches is very quick.

Because hashes normally involve very many comparisons, the relatively expensive hash calculation is done once for each key, and then once for each lookup. Imagine a hash with 10 entries. Building it will involve 10 calls to `hash`, before the first lookup is even done. The first lookup will be relatively quick though: one call to `hash`, followed by very efficient comparison of hash codes (it's actually faster than this, as they are "indexed"). If there is a match, one must still do a call to `eql?` to insure it's a real match. Indeed, two objects that are not `eql?` could have the same hash. The only guarantee is that two objects that are `eql?` must have the same hash, but two different objects could have the same too.

If you wanted to do the same using an `Array` instead, you might need 10 call to `eql?` for each lookup.

For what it's worth, I don't think the Ruby primer you link to is as clear as it could be. It neglects the fact that calculating the `hash` can be expensive, so that it's done only when it makes sense, i.e. when it is a good assumption that each element will be compared many times. Moreover, it's a shame that the example of a custom `eql?` it gives uses `==` to compare the instance variables. Ideally, it would use `eql?` for consistency, in the same way that arrays are `==` if its elements are `==` and arrays are `eql?` if its elements are `eql?`. Finally, it really should mention [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Struct.html) which defines decent `==`, `hash` and `eql?` for you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation here, this definitely helps clear it up as well

Answer (score 3):

For e.g. [`Array#hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-hash) says -

> Two arrays with the same content will have the same hash code (and will compare using eql?).

and [`Array#==`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D) says :

> Equality — Two arrays are equal if they contain the same number of elements and if each element is equal to (according to Object#==) the corresponding element in other_ary.

and [`Array#eql?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-eql-3F) says

> Returns true if self and other are the same object, or are both arrays with the same content.

So as per the documentation it is clear that `eql?` is faster as it uses `hash` value, with `eql?`. Whereas `#==` does two things -

> 1. length of the array and
> 2. each element equality test.

Comment: So why not compare using == rather than eql? Is it because eql uses hash codes which is a quicker comparison? Wouldn't it internally have to use == to compare the two hash codes for equivalence anyways?

Comment: This answer is wrong: `eql?` does not use `hash` value and is not faster than `==`.

Comment: Yeah, their source code is almost identical. (You can see it in docs by clicking.) I guess the difference is that `==` can convert other object to array if necessary (by calling to_ary method) while `eql?` enforces it to be of Array class only.

Comment: Oh, and they use their respective methods to compare the elements.

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa: Indeed. I've tried to make this a bit more explicit in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/017f0ffe1822264a8ead114f0b6055805185c0ac